# Change the style/css reference file for the specific division in Html using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jqgrid, styles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JQgrid change css of the add form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928974/jqgrid-change-css-of-the-add-form)

I want to change the `style/css` file reference for the specific `div` only in `HTML` page using `JQuery`. Here for example I have class `C1` which has different style in different css files. Now I want to change the reference for that spefic div only in the page, which will be referred to another css reference file, how can I do this runtime ?

Comment: first you should have mentioned this in your question,a tag is not enough, Second i thought you got your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928974/jqgrid-change-css-of-the-add-form, no?